# How to iterate over a CSV file and update values in one column based on the value of another column

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with one column titled 'pages' that is empty for all of the rows of the file. I want to fill in this empty value in each row based on the value of 'size' for that row. For example, if the size is less than 100, then I want the empty value to be replaced with 1, and if the 'size' value is greater than 100, I want the empty value to be replaced with 2. I am doing this in python. I have tried some things like:

```
data = pd.read_csv("example.csv")         
data["pages"] = ""      
data.to_csv("example.csv", index=False)
for row in data.iterrows(): 
    if row['size']>100:
        data["pages"]= "1"
```

but it is not working. I have uploaded an image of what the data may look like. [image] 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method to do it.Try this

```
data["pages"] = data["size"].apply(lambda x: "2" if x>100 else "1")
```

Or like this

```
data["pages"] = (data["size"]>100).map({True: '2', False: '1'})
```